# Reset AUTO_INCREMENT column in Rollback with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.1

I use Database Transactions with laravel 5.1 and MySql to rollback if an error has happened in insertion process,but i note AUTO_INCREMENT column not rollback as other columns, but i need rollback it so I do the following to achieve that

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE customers AUTO_INCREMENT = '.(count(Customer::all())+1).';');
```

**My Question**:

Does this way efficient enough or not because after my research  i found that **AUTO_INCREMENT** out of transactions scope and some people not recommended to use AUTO_INCREMENT with my needs.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: It sounds like you are using AUTO_INCREMENT for something that it isn't intended for. Also consider using `max()+1` instead of `count()+1` if you decide to do what you have shown here, though I'd advice against doing it to begin with.

Comment: so what is your advice to achieve that of your opinion.

Comment: What are your needs? Why do you need to rollback auto_increment at all? Usually developers in the learning-phase is annoyed by the fact that rows don't increase 1 by 1 and if one record jumps from 27 to 29 it's reason enough to dress out of your skin and die, but we just have to learn not to let our OCD speaks louder here. Auto Increments are not meant to be human readable data.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: thanks for your advice but please can you help me to make column to be unique and rollback if an error has happened   and be human readable data